# Why accompanying shared library to which the one requires it fail like:

Tags: debian, shared-library

As Debian program often lags of shared library / dependency, so accompanying it with the eligible shared library should work, i.e. by the same latest update of roll-based/quick update OS, e.g. Arch programs/packages

so just copy all package files from it to Debian OS in its own, here e.g program is **xbright** , its dep. copied to `/usr/local/lib`

but why accompanying shared library to which the one requires it altogether simply fails in such way:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib xbright =5

xbright: relocation error: /usr/local/lib/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_audit_symbind_alt version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
```

to clear by nice info, the failed one is

```
$ xbright =5
  xbright: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by xbright)
```

Help please, how to have it work as supposed to be ?

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic linker is also part of the C library, you need to copy that too. Check what `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` points to on Arch, and copy that to `/usr/local/lib`; then check that it’s working by running

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/ld-2.34.so xbright =5
```

(replacing `ld-2.34.so` with the appropriate name).

You can set your binaries up to use that interpreter by default using `patchelf`:

```
patchelf --set-interpreter /usr/local/lib/ld-2.34.so /usr/local/bin/xbright
```

You can also set the `RPATH` in `xbright` to point to `/usr/local/lib`, so you won’t need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` all the time:

```
patchelf --set-rpath /usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin/xbright
```